# MAAS IPMI Problem

Tags: maas, ipmi

System Info:

MAAS 2.2.2

Ubuntu: xenial

IPMI works in console command:

ipmitool -I Lan  -U xxxx -P xxxx -H x.x.x.x power status

Returns correct status of power

However MAAS interface with exact same IP and MAC returns:

***Error: Incorrect username. Check BMC configuration and try again.***

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was ***User Privilege***:

The IPMI user must be **Operator** to work on MAAS UI.

IPMI Users with any privilege can control the Server through IPMI Console Command.